# curl replaces double quotes to single quote in bash

Tags: linux, bash, variables, curl

I have this variable

```
TOKEN="Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXA"
```

when I add it to command curl

```
curl  -H "$TOKEN"  GET 'https://x.x.x.x/service/' --header 'Accept-Language: en'
```

when running, it replaces the **"** after -H to **'** to make the command like

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXA' GET https://x.x.x.x/service/ --header 'Accept-Language: en'
```

How to avoid that and make the command runs with **"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no quotes to replace.  They are already removed by the shell:

```
TOKEN="Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXA"
echo $TOKEN
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXA
```

If you would like to have double quotes around your string then change to:

```
TOKEN='"Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXA"'
echo $TOKEN
"Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXA"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that what you are seeing is the result of `set -x` or some other shell debug.

In this case it's perfectly correct. The `$TOKEN` has been evaluated and replaced with its value. The single quotes indicate to the shell that there is to be no further processing of the value. They are neither seen by `curl` nor passed on to the target host.